# Define new value-type for struct

Tags: c#

I was wondering if it was possible for one to make a struct or similar taking a value like a bool's true and false, but for example fluid, solid or gas. (Not a string-variable) Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds way more like [Enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) than a struct.

Comment: Enums *are* structs. :)  Or more precisely, enums and structs are both *value types*.

Comment: But not all structs are enums.  It sounds like he wants to use an Enum (regardless of inheritance) and all it's glory over creating his own Struct that would appear to have duplicate functionality to an Enum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you need is just this:

```
enum State { Fluid, Solid, Gas };
```

An enumeration of the states you have. So when you want to refer to the Fluid state, you just write this `State.Fluid`.

> Basically, enum is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type
>   that consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list.

For further documentation about `enum`, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx).

Comment: For estetics and possibly practicality, I would make it { Solid, Fluid, Gas }, which is the more natural progression. You could then test for one value being greater than the other and know something about the temperature.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are simple value types that map names to integral values or flags.

```
enum State
{
    Fluid,
    Solid,
    Gas
}
```

Internally, `State.Fluid` is just 0, `State.Solid` is 1 and `State.Gas` is 2. No strings are used during runtime, unless you use `ToString`.